# move the row in the hierarchical container below its sibling

Tags: java, vaadin7

I've got a `hierachicalContainer` that contains a lot of items.
I have a parent node with id `29` and have multiple child nodes with ids `30`, `47`, `54`.

Basically it looks like this

```
parent_element (29)
    child_element_1 (30)
    child_element_2 (47)
    child_element_3 (54)
```

I want to click on the button and move element `child_element_1` below `child_element_3` so it will look like this

```
parent_element
    child_element_2
    child_element_3
    child_element_1
```

In my button `click listener` I do it like this

```
Object tableItemId // child_element_1
Object parentId = hierachicalContainer.getParent(tableItemId);
List<?> relativesIds = new ArrayList<>(Optional.ofNullable(hierarchicalContainer.getChildren(parentId)).orElse(Collections.emptyList()));
Object previousItemId = null;
for (Object tableItemIdRel : relativesIds) {
    if (tableItemIdRel != tableItemId) {
        previousItemId = tableItemIdRel;
    }
}
hierarchicalContainer.moveAfterSibling(tableItemId, previousItemId);
```

But it does nothing. The element on UI is left where it was.

What is the problem?

Comment: Just to have it mentioned: trees in vaadin have drag and drop support; there are lots of examples out there and in the docs and it's way more userfriendly than let the user sort with buttons.

Comment: @cfrick you mean vaadin 8?

Comment: Yes, i assumed v8

Comment: @cfrick unfortunately I am stuck with 7